# Removing &nbsp; generated spaces in php

Tags: php, mysql, removing-whitespace

The problem I'm having is removing spaces. 
I've tried a few different ways and none of them have removed them. 
I have a drop down menu that has spaces in it so that all the times line up to be easily understood by a customer. It comes through like $str below. Main problem is that once its sent to the mysql database, it replaces the extra spaces with an A with an accent mark. The other problem is, it just doesn't look right in the end with the extra spaces for the customer to review before submitting. I'm not clear on the function of mysql_prep but its there as well with trim before the query is ran on the database.

I tried:

```
$str = "  9:00 AM  to  11:00 AM"
$time = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
echo $time; // OUTPUTS "  9:00AM  to  11:00AM" // THOSE SPACES DONT NEED TO BE REMOVED


$str = "  9:00 AM  to  11:00 AM"
$time = str_replace('  ', '', $str); //NOTE THE EXTRA SPACE
echo $time; // OUTPUTS "  9:00 AM  to  11:00 AM"    


$str = "  9:00 AM  to  11:00 AM"
$time = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $str); //EVEN TRIED THIS EVEN THOUGH THERES NO WAY
echo $time; // OUTPUTS "  9:00 AM  to  11:00 AM"
```

And

```
$str = "  9:00 AM  to  11:00 AM"
$time = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);
echo $time; // OUTPUTS "???9:00 AM??to??11:00 AM"//SEEMS CLOSEST BUT THE TRIANGLE QUESTION MARKS REPLACE THE SPACES


$str = "  9:00 AM  to  11:00 AM"
$time = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);
echo $time; // OUTPUTS "  9:00 AM  to  11:00 AM"
```

I even tried using explode and trim to do it in a round about way and even trim didn't remove the spaces.  Versions I'm using; PHP:5.3.4, MySQL:5.1.53 & Firefox:5.0.1

Comment: Your first `preg_replace` example works for me: http://codepad.org/tOfpVswD

Comment: What again is wrong with [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) or its brother `rtrim()` or its sister `ltrim()`?

Comment: getting an &Acirc; in your text indicates you've got a character set mis-match. Probably UTF-8 in one place, ISO-8859 in another.

Comment: @Shi: OP wishes to remove inner spaces as well.

Comment: Why is your question entitled `Removing &nbsp;` yet none of your examples operate on strings containing `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Your code
`$time = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str);` works for me.

Comment: Thats really odd that the first preg replace worked for you. Like I said, it worked to remove the spaces but it replaced them with black diamonds(not triangles like I said previously) with a question mark in them, diplayed in Firefox and IE 8. Maybe due to WAMP?

Comment: @webbiedave Why waste our time, really?

Comment: @Mark B I dont know much about charsets, where is this specified? At the top of the code in a page?

Comment: @JEH: Which question is wasting your time? The one referring to `mysql_prep` or `&nbsp;`? I'm trying to get clarification. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @webbiedave if you noticed, the &nbsps were generated, as in on another page. Have you ever seen &nbsp; come through from a form instead of a space? Do you not know what myql_prep is at all? I've just started and I'm aware it can be very important when the public has access to information queried on a db.

Comment: My comment was upvoted twice so I'm not the only one curious about it. `mysql_prep` is not a standard function. Quick research shows it to be an archaic function for use back in the bad ol' PHP 4 days. So, referencing a non-standard function that doesn't appear in your example code warrants a question. This ain't my first rodeo ;)

Comment: @webbiedave why is it that you're the only one with those problems understanding then?

Comment: @Mark B I attempted to use $str = utf8_encode($str); Would that have fixed the problem if that was it?

Comment: @webbiedave Why don't you go try to actually help someone instead of badgering someone for no reason to make yourself feel better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-breaking space is not a normal space.

```
str_replace("\xa0",'',$string);
```

Or to get all other whitespace in there:

```
preg_replace("/[\xa0\s]{2,}/",'',$string);
```

And be aware of character encoding, you seem to have some issues with that.

Comment: This is an answer that makes a lot of sense to me but for some reason, I'm not getting the opposite result.

Comment: Got it. It was a chunk of free code that I used using 8859-1 encoding. Once I switched it over and made a few small adjustments, this solution worked!

Comment: Yeah, had a problem editing my comment. Str_Replace gave me the black diamonds and preg_replace made no change with these initially. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this replaced the spaces with black diamonds with a question mark in them. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you happen to know anything about charsets that might help, ie UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

okay bit more code but works

```
$str = "  9:00 AM  to  11:00 AM";  

$find_cln = array (' ','to','AM','PM'); // find
$rep_cln = array ('',' to ',' AM',' PM'); // replace

$str = str_replace($find_cln, $rep_cln, $str);
```

Comment: Its been stated already that the OP wants to remove inner spaces as well, `trim()` and `rtrim()` will only remove whitespace characters from the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: That would work but I'm also trying to remove the extra space before and after to as well. Thanks for your time.